# How to list all tags in a certain Mercurial branch?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to list the tags only on a certain branch? (from command line preferably)

For example:

```
$ hg branch test1
... (make some commits)
$ hg tag mytag_on_test1_branch

$ hg branch test2
... (make some commits)
$ hg tag mytag_on_test2_branch
... (make some commits)
$ hg tag mytag_on_test2_branch_2
```

Now `hg tags` returns:

```
$ hg tags
tip                                5:34603c3a4107
mytag_on_test2_branch_2            4:72db17d2170c
mytag_on_test2_branch              2:09aed50d8b95
mytag_on_test1_branch              0:d43c48c0e1d8
```

I would only like to see tags on branch "test2", like this:

```
mytag_on_test2_branch_2            4:72db17d2170c
mytag_on_test2_branch              2:09aed50d8b95
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like so often, the answer lies in the proper use of revsets; they are a powerful tool to limit the revision ranges to nearly whatever need. See `hg help revsets` for details.

In your case  we also make use of the output templating to only get shown the tags instead of full log output of those revisions. Thus if you need all tags for THISBRANCH:

```
hg log --rev="branch(THISBRANCH) and tag()" --template="{tags}\n"
```

**Sample output for widely-tagged repo**

```
hgsubversion>hg log -r "branch(stable) and tag()" -T "{tags}\n"
1.5.1
1.6.1
1.6.2
1.6.3
1.7
1.8
1.8.1
1.8.2
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this solution seems to only output the first tag in a branch, not all of them. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It lists all tags for me which belong to that exact branch. It does exclude tags which are ancestors but not in the same branch as THISBRANCH (e.g. in the branches that THISBRANCH was branched off)

Comment: I have updated the example - when I execute `hg log --rev="branch(test2) and tag()" --template="{tags}\n"` I get only one result (`mytag_on_test2_branch`), the other one (`mytag_on_test2_branch_2`) is missing.

Comment: It does for me. See this transcript: https://paste.openttdcoop.org/p2smlxnu4 (Using hg 3.5.1)

Comment: Mind, you can tag any revision in any branch, if you explicitly specify a revision to tag. Are you sure that all your tags are in the branch you think they are? Also: what mercurial version do you use? Can you share your repo or the exact test case to reproduce (verbatim as in my paste)?

Comment: Interesting... If I run your example I only get `tag2` (without `tag2b`). I am guessing it has to do with my Mercurial version then (2.2.2)... Also, `hg log` doesn't support `-G` option. Thanks for helping out, I'll upgrade Mercurial and use your way of getting the tags!